# How to move installed apk from phone memory to sdcard on android 6.0.1 without root

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-j5

Move installed apk from phone memory to sdcard on android 6.0.1 without root and install new apk to sdcard.
My device is Samsung Galaxy J5 (SM-J500H os updated to 6.0.1). Phone's memory is too small to use install big applications and games. I installed asphalt 8 but cache files are too big for phone memory. What can i do?

Comment: Add SD card as adoptable sorage, here is how to: http://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, unless your OEM did something very nonstandard, you can't.

Marshmallow has no facility to move apps to the SD card as that feature was removed in favor of adopted storage in the core operating system. In adopted or internal storage mode, the SD card is essentially "adopted" or brought into the internal storage as if it is built into the device. This method is not without drawbacks though, your SD card will become encrypted and can only be read by that device (not in another phone or computer) and it will put significantly more wear on the card which is a concern because SD card storage has a finite number of writes before becoming unusable. Adopted storage is also slower than standard internal storage in general.

Even with adopted storage you don't chose what to move, the operating system does that... And some apps cannot reside on the SD card even with adopted storage.

Comment: Is there a way to take a phone that comes with this awful OS "feature" (typical Google "all your belongs to us" totalitarian-behavior) and revert it to Android 5.x, so we can have workable SD-Storage (readable in other devices, separate, etc) again?  My wife got a phone with this on it, and it is also 1/2 the speed of my same-Ram/Cpu phone, that runs on Android 5.x, so there is performance to be gained, as well.

Comment: @JosephK Depends on the specific device, there is no blanket answer, but in general OEMs do not support downgrading. You do not have to adopt the SD card, when you insert it you can leave it as External Storage, and it can be read in any computer or device like it always could, the drawback is apps cannot be moved to it.

Comment: "apps cannot be moved to it..."  Exactly, so the phone runs out of space almost instantly, making it worthless.  But it's so slow with this version of Android, it's not far from worthless right out of the box.  I suppose saying, "Comes with new Android" (keeping up with the Jones's) sells more phones than, "Doesn't hang for a long time when you do something."  The best workaround we found was to disable all the Google-ware that came on it, which helped a lot (those, auto-updated, had it full without any "actually desired software" installed).

Answer (score 0):

The actual .apk itself is never on the SD card, and there is no need to do that either. The data can be moved (at times only partially) to the SD card.
If thats what you intended in asking, then see if your phone supports move to SD in the settings under applications. If not, you can root (at your own risk) and use Apps2SD or similar apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move apps at all without root, but you can use apk editor pro to change the storage to prefer external on other device whose storage is free ,it does not require rooting.

And there is no other way without rooting.